# call java script function with argument from asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

```
   <div style="float: left">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:chatWith('Ankit')">
                            <asp:Label ID="NameLbl2" Text='<%# Eval("Values")  %>' runat="server"></asp:Label></a></div>
```

this is the code that I am using inside a repeater with a java script function `onclick="javascript:chatWith('userName')"` , I want to use another name at the place of "userName" with the help of "EVAL()".??????

Answer (score 1):

If the `userName`field is member of *dataSource* then use `Eval()`:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" 
   onclick=javascript:chatWith('<%# Eval("userName") %>')>
   Someting...
</a>
```